# Query not returning correct results in function

Tags: php, mysql, function

The following function is set up to:

1. Collect the `user_id` from my database, as you can see below `WHERE subscriber = '$user'`. And then:
2. return the possible multiple values that `user_id` are.

However, when I've tried to use this function, it has only collected an array, with the key `0`, and value `user_id`. For apparent reasons I want the array to contain the numerical value that is in the `user_id` column in my database with the key `user_id`.

```
function get_subscribitions($user)
{
    $user = mysql_real_escape_string ($user);

    $sql = "SELECT 'user_id' FROM `subscribe` WHERE subscriber = '$user'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $rows = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);

    return $rows;
}
```

Can anyone please pinpoint where I'm making the error leading to these related problems?

Any help appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
 function get_subscribitions($user)
{

$user = mysql_real_escape_string ($user);

  $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM `subscribe` WHERE subscriber = '$user'";

 $result = mysql_query($sql);

  $rows = array();

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $rows[] = $row['user_id'];
  }

  mysql_free_result($result);

  return $rows;
}
```

There were unnecessary quotes in the query and you were not reading the $row array properly

Comment: In what way was I not reading the $row array properly? I implemented your code and got an index undefined, do you have any idea why that happened?

Comment: If you have say 2 results - 5, and 11, using `$rows[] = $row;` you wound up with `$rows = array(0 => array('user_id' => 5), 1 => array('user_id' => 11));`. Using my code you wound up with `$rows = array(0 => 5, 1 => 11)`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thanks a lot. However, user_id became undefined when I used your code,and I don't really know what to do about that.

Comment: You're welcome. What do you mean became undefined? Do you mean you get a warning or something? With the code in my answer the function returns either an array like the one I've described in the previous comment - `array(0 => 5, 1 => 11)` or it could return an empty array if the query doesn't return any rows. I guess you're trying to read the result in some strange way, but without more code I can only guess.

Answer (score 3):

Try instead

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM `subscribe` WHERE subscriber = '$user'";
```

Notice the single quotes missing from around `user_id`